# AutoCompleteTextView function afterTextChanged calls everytime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I have one autoCompleteTextView in my app in which when user finishes typing it checked its afterTextChanged method and redirected user to next- detail page based to codes entered by user but the problem is this when user click back from detail page it again switches to detail page. The afterTextChanged method calls everytime. I have called it in onCreatedView method. How can I prevent from it. Please help.

Code:

```
         actSearchCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //do nothing


            String product_code = actSearchCode.getText().toString();

            Log.e("TAG", "afterTextChanged: " );

            if(getCodeType.equals("art")) {

                if (actSearchCode.getText().length() != 0 && actSearchCode.getText().length() >= 5) {

                    singleProductDetailList = databaseHelper.getProductByArtCode(product_code);

                    if (singleProductDetailList.size() != 0) {

                        Fragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("product_art", product_code);
                        bundle.putString("source_type", "ean");

                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    } else {

                        singleUnrecognisedCheck = new ArrayList<>();
                        singleUnrecognisedCheck = databaseHelper.getUnrecognisedByCode(product_code);

                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.beep);
                        mp.start();

                        if (singleUnrecognisedCheck.size() == 0) {
                            getDialog();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.unrecognised_code_has_been_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
                else{

                if (actSearchCode.getText().length() != 0 && actSearchCode.getText().length() >= 13) {

                    singleProductDetailList = databaseHelper.getProductByArtCode(product_code);

                    if (singleProductDetailList.size() != 0) {

                        Fragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("product_art", product_code);
                        bundle.putString("source_type", "ean");

                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    } else {

                        singleUnrecognisedCheck = new ArrayList<>();
                        singleUnrecognisedCheck = databaseHelper.getUnrecognisedByCode(product_code);

                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.beep);
                        mp.start();

                        if (singleUnrecognisedCheck.size() == 0) {

                            codeValue = 1;

                            getDialog();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.unrecognised_code_has_been_added, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }

                }

                }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                imgClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgSourceClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                imgClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgSourceClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });


    // article code start

    modelProductCodeList.clear();
    productCodeList.clear();


    if (getCodeType.equals("art")) {
        modelProductCodeList = databaseHelper.getProductsArticleCode();

        for (int k = 0; k < modelProductCodeList.size(); k++) {

            productCodeList.add( modelProductCodeList.get(k).getArticle_code());


        }
        actSearchCode.setAdapter(null);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, productCodeList);
        actSearchCode.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    rgGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {


            if (i == R.id.rdbArticleCode) {


                actSearchCode.setText("");
                getCodeType = "art";

                modelProductCodeList = databaseHelper.getProductsArticleCode();

                databaseHelper.close();
                productCodeList.clear();

                for (int k = 0; k < modelProductCodeList.size(); k++) {
                    productCodeList.add(modelProductCodeList.get(k).getArticle_code());

                }

                actSearchCode.setAdapter(null);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, productCodeList);
                actSearchCode.setAdapter(adapter);


            } else if (i == R.id.rdbEANCode) {

                actSearchCode.setText("871128");

                getCodeType = "ean";
                modelProductCodeList = databaseHelper.getProductsEANCode();

                databaseHelper.close();
                productCodeList.clear();
                for (int k = 0; k < modelProductCodeList.size(); k++) {
                    productCodeList.add(modelProductCodeList.get(k).getEan_code());

                    Log.e("TAG", "onCheckedChanged: "+modelProductCodeList.get(k).getEan_code() );

                }

                actSearchCode.setAdapter(null);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, productCodeList);
                actSearchCode.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    });


    actSearchCode.setThreshold(3);
    actSearchCode.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(actSearchCode.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

            Fragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("product_art", (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) );
            bundle.putString("source_type", getCodeType);

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: show your full code ?

Comment: @SushilKumar done. please check

Answer (score 2):

```
        final static boolean flag=false;//define this in the class before on create/on createView


        ----------


        actSearchCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    //do nothing

         if(!flag)
        {


                    Log.e("TAG", "afterTextChanged: " );

                    if(getCodeType.equals("art")) {

                        if (actSearchCode.getText().length() != 0 && actSearchCode.getText().length() >= 5) {

                            singleProductDetailList = databaseHelper.getProductByArtCode(product_code);

                            if (singleProductDetailList.size() != 0) {

                           flag=true;

                                Fragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // this is basically context of the class
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("product_art", product_code);
                                bundle.putString("source_type", "ean");

                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();


                            } 
  }else{
        flag=false;
        }
```

Comment: No, I can't. I need only this functionality in my app.

Comment: try this@mishti